# How can I group data returned in JSON format and return it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string of the form:

```
[
    {"ID":153,"CircuitID":53,"StartTime":"2014-11-12 12:45:00","EventFormatID":224,"TotalPlaces":8,"BookedPlaces":0,"ProvisionalPlaces":0},
    {"ID":161,"CircuitID":53,"StartTime":"2014-11-12 17:15:00","EventFormatID":224,"TotalPlaces":0,"BookedPlaces":0,"ProvisionalPlaces":0},
    {"ID":734,"CircuitID":53,"StartTime":"2014-11-12 18:30:00","EventFormatID":231,"TotalPlaces":14,"BookedPlaces":0,"ProvisionalPlaces":0}
]
```

In place of Event Format ID and Circuit ID I will be returning the names

What I need to do is group the results by Event Format ID and return the results in the following format:

```
Event 224 : 12:45 (8 places available), 17:15 (0 places available)
Event 231 : 18:30 (14 places available)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the data, group it by Event Format ID to present it in the required format!

Thanks

Comment: This is 1-to-many.  You will need to create an object where each Event Format ID is a key and the value for each key is an array of relevant objects.  Each element of the value array will be an object with keys and values from the original JSON.  All of this can be done manually in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use any additional libraries?  I'd use [lo-dash](https://lodash.com) which would make this relatively simple:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(data, "EventFormatID");
_(grouped).forEach(function (group, key) {
    console.log("Event:" + key);
    _(group).forEach(function (course) {
        console.log(course.StartTime + " (" + course.TotalPlaces + " places available)");
    });
});
```

Obviously the example above logs to the console but it'd be fairly simple to change to build up whatever string or object you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier with lodash/underscore, or even with ES5 array and object methods, but since you asked about pure JS:

```
var data = {}, results = [], i, j, id, time, obj, evts; // obj is your object above
for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
  id = obj[i].EventFormatID;
  time = obj[i].StartTime; // you can simplify to get just the time, not the datetime, if you prefer
  data[id] = data[id] || [];
  data[id].push({"time":time,"places":obj[i].TotalPlaces});
}
// now you have a proper data structure, just print it out
for (i in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    // just show the output properly formatted
    evts = [];
    for (j=0;i<data[i].length;j++) {
       evts.push(data[i][j].time+" ("+data[i][j].places+" places available)");
    }
    results.push("Event "+i+" : "+evts.join(","));
  }
}
```

ES5 makes this so much easier

```
var data = {}, results = [], obj; // obj is your object above
obj.forEach(function(val,i) {
  data[val.EventFormatID] = data[val.EventFormatID] || [];
  data[val.EventFormatID].push({"time":val.StartTime,"places":val.TotalPlaces});
});
// now you have a proper data structure, just print it out
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = data[key], evts = [];
  value.forEach(function(elm) {
     evts.push(elm.time+" ("+elm.places+" places available)");
  });
  results.push("Event "+key+" : "+evts.join(","));
});
```

And lodash is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look that:

http://jsfiddle.net/m260n5ud/

html

```
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

js

```
function tidyUp(jsonArray) {
    var myObject = {};
    for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
        var key = jsonArray[i]['EventFormatID'];
        var time = jsonArray[i]['StartTime'].replace(' ', ':').split(/[- :]/);
        time = time[3] + ":" + time[4];
        var totalPlace = jsonArray[i]['TotalPlaces'];

        if (myObject[key] == null) {
            myObject[key] = "Event : " + key + " : " + time + " ( " + totalPlace + " places available)";
        } else {
            myObject[key] += ", " + time + " ( " + totalPlace + " places available)";
        }
    }
    console.log(myObject);

    for (var k in myObject) {
        document.getElementById('contentDiv').innerHTML += myObject[k] + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to 3rd party plugin you can use this pure js code.  Can you check?